# How to make a formula into an array

Tags: filter, google-sheets, transpose, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have the following formula in Google Sheets that I am trying to make into an array:

```
=TRANSPOSE(FILTER(AddressBook!A2:A,AddressBook!S2:S=A1))
```

Tried various different approaches but none have worked.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please add some input and expected output. This will it make clearer for everybody and maybe a wandering programmer which might then also understand. (please use the code formatting for your code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try perhaps like this:

```
=TRANSPOSE(ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1:A, 
 {AddressBook!S2:S, AddressBook!A2:A}, 2, 0))))
```